# Как добавить параметр к url?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Помогите добавить к текущей странице параметр.

**С перезагрузкой страницы**, по факту у меня сейчас просто ссылка которая добавляет параметр
`<a href="?region_id=34">Ссылка</a>`
Например, к обычной текущей ссылке:
`https://example.com/`
я просто добавляю
`https://example.com/?region_id=34`
Это у срабатывает так как нужно.

Но как добавить условие, если уже какие-то параметры существуют?
Например к такой ссылке:
`https://example.com/customers/1?login=username`
Чтобы получилась ссылка вида:
`https://example.com/customers/1?login=username&region_id=34`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript - вот тут метод который вам нужен

Comment: если честно, я его видел, но не смог разобраться. точнее я не понял как туда подставить нужное мне key и value, т.е. мои region_id и region.id

Comment: @dmitriy ответ был точно по вашему примеру, сейчас обновлю его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это просто сделать.
пример есть такая ссылка:

```
<a class="test_url" href="https://example.com/customers/1?login=username">Ссылка</a>
```

С помощью `jQuery` берем атрибут `href` и добавляем в него то что нам нужно:
С помощью `indexOf` ищем есть ли в линке уже переменные или нет, если есть уже знак `?` значит переменные уже есть, а если нет добавляем первую.

```
var params = 'region_id=34';
if($('.test_url').attr('href').indexOf('?') === -1){
    $('.test_url').attr('href',$('.test_url).attr('href')+'?'+myparams);
}
else{
    $('.test_url').attr('href',$('.test_url).attr('href')+'&'+myparams);
}
```

Comment: опять же это если параметры там есть, а если их нет, тогда вместо `&` надо использовать `?`

Comment: @dmitriy Так устроит?

Comment: только в $('.test_url) тут кавычки не хватает ;-)

 ...$('.test_url')...